# MySQL Simultanious Connections

Tags: php, mysql

I have a PHP/MySQL website and it is hosted on Shared hosting. This website is not a huge traffic site. But I got an error (**Too Many Connections Error**) frequently. The hosting provider said that **25 MySQL connections at a time**

I am using two functions for database connections, initDB() and closeDB()

```
    function initDB()
    {
            $connection = mysql_connect($DatabaseURL,$DatabaseUName,$DatabasePWord);
            if($connection)
            {
                $db = mysql_select_db($DatabaseName,$connection);
            }
            return $connection;
    }

    function closeDB($connection)
    {
        mysql_close($connection);
    }
```

gettings data from database

```
    $connection = initDB();

    //executing MySQL query

    closeDB($connection);
```

This is working fine, but sometime got Too Many Connections Error.

In my website, **initDB()** and **closeDB()** functions are called 76 times.
I am sure the opened connections are closed after execution

If any problem in the above code

How can i solve the **Too Many Connections Error**

Comment: Your best bet is to get a better hosting company

Comment: I am using Hostgator shared hosting

Comment: you need better hosting and 25 MySQL connections at a time is quite low

Comment: you should not be connecting/disconnecting 76 times in a single script. connect **ONCE**. unless you have very very specific requirements, that *ONE* connection can be reused multiple times. indeed. if you're using transactions, you **MUST** use the same connection, otherwise your transactions will be terminated/rolled-back

Comment: Thanks for your reply.How can i reuse the same connection?Please tell me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use fast-hack of your code using [static](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.static.php).

```
function initDB()
{
        static $connection;
        if (!$connection) //establish connection only once
        {
            $connection = mysql_connect($DatabaseURL,$DatabaseUName,$DatabasePWord);
            if($connection)
            {
                $db = mysql_select_db($DatabaseName,$connection);
            }
        }
        return $connection;
}

function closeDB($connection)
{
    //no need to close.
}
```